# Is there any alternative of Intent to send data for Class (Not Activity)?

Tags: android

Previously, I was using activities in my project and was sending data using **Intent** from one activity to another which works perfectly fine.

Now requirement changes, and I have to show all things on Dialogs, instead of activities, so there will separate 3-4 dialog class and single activity.

Now I want the same flow on dialog also, but there is a problem to pass data temporarily exactly how intent works!

I tried with Singleton, but the problem is it remains data until the whole lifecycle, but I don't want that.

I can't use the interface also because there are lots of things to pass.

Also, I can't use bundle fundle n all those, because this all depends on runtime, I meant it depends upon if user fill input

Question: How can I pass data from one class to another class or activity? and it should not save value for the whole lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

statically sending data is an option but its not good way, because memory to static variables is assigned at Application level and can be cleared when memory needed. The best way is to use

**Object Oriented approach**

For example if you have a class, You can send data in class constructor, or can send it through function call

```
class class1 
{

  public class1(Object data) { // constructor
      // you can use this data
  }

   //// Or through function call

   public void func(Object data) { // this method can be called by other classes which has its object
       // you can use this data
   }
}
```

Now lets assume you have another class

```
class class2
{
    class1 obj = new class1(your_data_object); // if you want to send through constructor

    void someMethod() {

         obj.func(your_data_object); // send data whatever you want to send
    }
}
```

Obviously your case will not be as simple as my example, but to handle complex cases you can implement interfaces.

**Interface Example**

define an interface

```
interface myListener {
  public void listen(Object data);
}
```

now lets say you want to call class2 method from class1. then class2 must implement this interface.

```
public class class2 implements myListener {
@override
public void listen(Object data)
{
   /// you got data here, do whatever you want to do that with that data.
}
}
```

Now in class1 if you have interface object you can call class2 method

```
interfaceRef.listen(your_data);
```

Comment: there are so many things, that I can't make interface and lots of parameter

Comment: actually you need to adjust according to requirements, somewhere you can send simply in constructors and can send through function calls, some where you need to  implement interface.

Comment: There is no alternative to Intent?

Comment: no, intent is only for activities calls, to communicate between simple classes, basic object oriented approach is used.

Comment: @AnishaSingh is it working now? let me know if you face any other issue. If its working please upvote & accept my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with EventBus or BroadCastReceivers to pass data accordingly in local variables.

EventBus is a publish/subscribe event bus for Android and Java. EventBus... simplifies the communication between components. decouples event senders and receivers. performs well with Activities, Fragments, and background threads.

http://greenrobot.org/eventbus

First Register to EventBus in your Activity

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
}
```

Now pass the data from anywhere ,whether it is activity/fragment/background service etc etc etc like :

```
 EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent("your data here");
```

Now in your activity receive this message like :

```
  @Subscribe(sticky = true,threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
            Log.e("TAG","Event Received");
            Log.e("TAG",event.getData);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain with very basic example